# ember generate cordova-init throwing EPERM error

Tags: android, cordova, ember.js

I'm trying to run sample which is given in docs/getting started, but consistently throwing the following error (tried with different windows box).
`ember generate cordova-init com.poeticsystems.hello --platform=android`

```
Path: platforms\android
Package: com.poeticsystems.hello
Name: Hello
Activity: MainActivity
Android target: android-25
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Android project created with cordova-android@6.1.1
Discovered plugin "cordova-plugin-whitelist" in config.xml. Adding it to the
project
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-whitelist@1" via npm
Installing "cordova-plugin-whitelist" for android

    This plugin is only applicable for versions of cordova-android greater
    than 4.0. If you have a previous platform version, you do *not* need
    this plugin since the whitelist will be built in.

Adding android platform to cordova...
Update config.xml with your project settings...EPERM: operation not
permitted, symlink '..\dist' -> 'N:\DEV\ember-cordova\hello\cordova\www'
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, symlink '..\dist' -> 'N:\DEV\ember
cordova\hello\cordova\www'
at Error (native)
```

os: win32 x64
node - 4.4.2
npm - 2.15.0
ember-cli: 2.4.3
cordova - 6.5.0
ember-cli-cordova: 0.1.0-beta-2

I have modified value of locationType to 'hash'.
Could anyone please help to resolve this.

Comment: try running command prompt as Administrator..it looks like permission issue for doing symlink

Comment: Many Thanks @kumkanillam. It worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Error: EPERM: operation not permitted

This denotes some thing with permission issue. Mostly in windows if we run `cmd` as `Run as Administrator` will solve these sort of issues.